# How to loop through a custom field for each post, & display?

Tags: categories, custom-field, loop

I'm working on a category page. I want to show all the posts that belong to that category on  one page. Each  post makes use of a custom field that I have added. I want to loop through the posts to display them after each other, & show the custom field value that belongs to each post as well.

How do I loop through the custom fields to get the value that belongs to each post? I want to display this value next to the rest of each post. I am working with a plugin called advanced events manager.

My code  to get the value of the custom field for each post so far, that doesn't work:

```
$latest_cpt = get_posts("post_type=event"); 
$theidone =$latest_cpt[0]->ID;
$this_post_id =  $theidone; //get_the_ID();
$key_2_value =  get_post_meta( $this_post_id, 'custom_select', true );
if( ! empty( $key_2_value )) {
$thisisworking =   $key_2_value ;
 ;}
echo $thisisworking;
```

My code only get the custom field value for the first post, how can I get the custom field value for each post? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing "foreach" loop. Try this way

```
    $latest_cpt = get_posts("post_type=event"); 
foreach ( $latest_cpt as $cpt_post ) {    
$theidone =$cpt_post->ID;
    $this_post_id =  $theidone; //get_the_ID();
    $key_2_value =  get_post_meta( $this_post_id, 'custom_select', true );
    if( ! empty( $key_2_value )) {
    $thisisworking =   $key_2_value ;
     ;}
    echo $thisisworking; }
```